# SpringCodegen generates class with JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY instead of JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY

Tags: java, spring, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

One field is not showing anymore in the deserialization of the json.

It happened because our code generator is transforming the OpenApi definition into this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
```

Before it was working because it translated into:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
```

This code is generated from an openapi: 3.0.2 yml file with SpringCodegen.

Does anyone know if I can tell in the open api definition or in the maven openApi plugin to generate the code to use: JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY?

We are using Java 11

Thank you very much

Regards.

In my local test It worked with JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY and JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY but the code is generated with  JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY which I cannot change in the generated clases.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it is not possible to configure openapi generator's `JsonTypeInfo` generation. These definitions are hard-coded in mustache templates in openapi generator codebase.

To see how `JsonTypeInfo` are generated, I would suggest the following:

- clone [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) repo.
- checkout the tag corresponding to the version of openapi generator you are using.
- find the mustache templates. They should be under
  `openapi-generator/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/`.
- find the corresponding generator and look at `typeInfoAnnotation.mustache` template .

You may want to checkout other tags to find the version that generate the `JsonTypeInfo` you expect, if any.

Note: I could not find any reference to `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` in  openapi generator v3.0.2